# inject image in between every ng-repeat using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working in angularjs application, i have used ng-repeat in my application but i need to insert images in between every ng-repeat loop dynamically.

Is it possible to inject image inbetween every ng-repeat.

> sample xml file

```
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<revista>
    <notas>
    <banner>No</banner>
    <bannerFuente></bannerFuente>
    <bannerURL></bannerURL>
    <copete>Editorial</copete>
        <titulo>Se armó en grande</titulo>
        <seccion>Opinión</seccion>
    </notas>
    <notas>
    <banner>No</banner>
    <bannerFuente></bannerFuente>
    <bannerURL></bannerURL>
    <copete>Perfiles de clientes</copete>
        <titulo>¿Quién se llevó mi negocio?</titulo>
        <seccion>Opinión</seccion>
    </notas>
    <notas>
    <banner>No</banner>
    <bannerFuente></bannerFuente>
    <bannerURL></bannerURL>
    <copete>Gestión empresarial</copete>
        <titulo>Gestión para pequeños negocios</titulo>
        <seccion>Opinión</seccion>
    </notas>
</revista>`
```

> js file

```
    $http.get('sample.xml').then(function(response)
         { 
             var dom = response.data;
             $scope.posts = dom.revista.notas;
         })
```

> html file with ng-repeat and swiper

```
<div class="swiper-container" ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="key in posts">
                    <div class="mag_content_wrap con_style1">
                        <div class="cls_favorite_sec editorial_page1">
                            <h2>{{key.seccion}}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cls_favorite_sec editorial_page">
                            <div class="cls_inner1 img_r">
                                <p class="img_con">
                                    <img src="Imagenes/{{key.imagen}}" />
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cls_inner2 editorial_page2">
                                <h2>{{key.copete}}</h2>
                                <h3>{{key.titulo}}</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In the above code ng-repeat shows three pages properly, but i need to load image inbetween every page after swipe. If i swipe first content it should shows image and if i swipe image it shows second content and vice versa.

Comment: Please show us your current code.

Comment: It is possible. But your question is pretty broad and you always need to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @Michelem,  Here i have attach the link which shows my issue, [Plinker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8I6mWw6nAnE1WbonZVbG?p=preview). I need to insert advertisement inbetween every page (after single swipe). Is it possible to load image like this.

Comment: Hi @LordTribual,  Here i have attach the link which shows my issue, [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8I6mWw6nAnE1WbonZVbG?p=preview). I need to insert advertisement inbetween every page (after single swipe). Is it possible to load image like this.

Comment: Its pretty hard to tell from your short description. You should update your question and explain your problem in detail. Show code snippets and point people to your problem.

Comment: Hi @LordTribual, I have edited my question please suggest an idea to fix the problem.